# NumberFormatException mistake

Tags: java

So I am trying to calculate the average for data in a set. Here is what I have

```
         int total = 0;
         for(int i = 1; i < field.length; i++) {
             total += Integer.parseInt(field[i]);
         }

         double avg = (double)total/(field.length-1);
         System.out.println("average score: " + avg);
```

The data is like
2007,Alabama,252
2008,Alabama,232
2004,Alabama,172

for example I want to calculate (252+172+232)/3
and I get that error

Help please

Comment: What is stored in `field[i]`? What is the full exception message?

Comment: the full exception message is really long. It takes data from a file that has many states and numbers. But it only says specifically for Alabama
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Alabama"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Well...is `Alabama` a number? Please read what `parseInt` does.

Comment: oh i forgot the mention
String record = input.nextLine();
String[] field = record.split(",");
i split the string so i can read the third term as an integer

Comment: Is field[0] = "2007,Alabama,252" or is field[0]="2007", field[1]="Alabama", field[2]="252"?

Comment: field[0] would be 2007. field[1] is alabama and field[2] is the 252

Comment: and field[i] should be field[2] every time because of the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that your data is like A, B, C, A, B, C - where the "C"'s are the numbers that you want to average, then you should say:

```
     int total = 0;
     for(int i = 2; i < field.length; i+=3) {  // Notice the changes here
         total += Integer.parseInt(field[i]);
     }

     double avg = (double)total/(field.length/3); // Notice this change
     System.out.println("average score: " + avg);
```

(But I'd also suggest that you'd be better off creating a new class, like `StateRecord`, that has member variables of `int year`, `String state`, and `int value` - then, go through your `StateRecord` instances and just pull out each record's `value`.)